# choosing kernel for digit recognition in C

Tags: c++, svm

I'm trying to classify digits read on images at known positions in C++, using SVM.
for that, I sample over a rectangle at the known position of the digit, I train with a ground_truth.

I wonder how to choose the kernel of the SVM. I use the default linear kernel but my intuition tell me that it might not be the best choice.

How could I choose the kernel?

Comment: Are the digits you're trying to classify hand-written?

Comment: If so this will help: https://mlss.soe.ucsc.edu/sites/default/files/malik-lec2.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to tune the kernel (if you use a nonlinear one). This guide may be useful for you: [A practical guide to SVM classification](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf)

Comment: +1 For referencing the libsvm guide. A very recommended resource.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not a magic bullet for this, so experimentation is your best friend.

Probably I would start with RBF which tends to work decently in most cases, and I am agreed with your intuition that probably linear is not the best, although some times (especially when you have tons of data) it can give you good surprises :)

The problem I have found with RBF is that it tends to overfit the training set, this stop to be an issue if you have a lot of data but then a new problem raises because it tends to scale poorly and having slow training time for big data.